# Unable to Get DHCP Lease - dhcps: send_offer>>udp_sendto result ffffffff

Tags: esp32

When connecting to an ESP32 in softAP mode from an ESP32 client, the client connects and disconnects just fine for a while. Eventually, the AP will show the following error:

dhcps: send_offer>>udp_sendto result ffffffff

The client connects but doesn't get a lease. If I try to connect from another device, like my
iPhone, it doesn't get a lease either. If I set the client as static, it works just fine even after the server stops responding to DHCP request. Stopping and starting the DHCP server doesn't fix it.

I'm using AsyncTCP (me-no-dev Oct 17, 2019 version) on the server. I'm using the 1.12.2 Espressif 32 board library in PlatformIO. (Didn't work with 1.12.1 either)

Any idea why I'm unable to obtain a lease? Rebooting the AP does fix the issue so it doesn't appear to be an issue with the client.

Answer (score 1):

I ran out of heap space. In AsyncTCP you have to explicitly free and delete the point.

https://gitter.im/espressif/arduino-esp32?at=5d6d213329dba2421ceea2c8